# HMS Wallet Kit-Error code -1 is returned when I add passes on the device side

Tags: huawei-mobile-services

I've downloaded the sample project of the Android client from the [HUAWEI Developers official website](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMS-Examples/wallet-sample-code-android)

After installing it on the mobile phone, I want to add a membership card to HUAWEI Wallet. 
The demo provides two methods for adding a pass. The key code is as follows:

```
public void saveToHuaWeiWallet(View view) {
    String jwtStr = getJwtFromAppServer(passObject);
    CreateWalletPassRequest request = CreateWalletPassRequest.getBuilder()
            .setJwt(jwtStr)
            .build();
    Log.i("testwalletKIT", "getWalletObjectsClient");
    walletObjectsClient = Wallet.getWalletPassClient(PassTestActivity.this);
    Task<AutoResolvableForegroundIntentResult> task = walletObjectsClient.createWalletPass(request);
    ResolveTaskHelper.excuteTask(task, PassTestActivity.this, SAVE_TO_ANDROID);
}
```

No matter which method I use for adding a pass, error code -1 is returned. I didn't find any description of the error code in the official documentation. Can anyone tell me why error code -1 is returned? [image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Parameter error. The possible causes are as follows:

1. No template is created for the passes. Add a template by referring to the following. https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMS-Guides/wallet-guide-webpage
2. The pass has already been added. Enter the unique ID (serinumber) of another pass.
3. The template ID and service number are incorrect. Enter the values of passStyleIdentifier and passTypeIdentifier fields used during template creation on the server side.
4. Incorrect IssuerId. Enter the app ID generated app creation in AppGallery Connect.